# Session creation for two different servers

Tags: php, session, cookies

I had two website in different servers. Both website had same headers. so if login one server website and going to another website i want same session in this website. how to pass the session values to this server.

And also if logout server means both servers sessions need to distory.

Give me the best options.

Comment: Are they subdomains of same domain?

Comment: You need to store the session data in some kind of storrage that both servers can access, it could be a shared file system, but it would probably be prefferable to use a system like memcache.

Comment: @  Jesper Bunny Jensen No.. Both are different servers. Main website one server. sub website are there in different server. so based how i can create a session for both servers.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've got two.

1. (Bad Option)
   It's not the most secure option but you can pass the session as a parameter. You would first use the serialize function. (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)
   Example:

   ```
   session_start();        
   $_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
   $_SESSION['animal']   = 'cat';
   $_SESSION['time']     = time();
   $foo = serialize($_SESSION);a:3:
   echo '<br /><a href="page2.php?' . $foo. '">page 2</a>';
   ```

   $foo would look like this: {s:8:"favcolor";s:5:"green";s:6:"animal";s:3:"cat";s:4:"time";i:1385023361;};` I would probably add on some sort of encoding if you choose to go this route.
2. (Better Option) 
   Store the session data in a database. You could then access it from any domain.